# autocomplete and $.getJSON problem

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, getjson

I have a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#PrincipleMember_IdNumber").autocomplete({
        close: function(event, ui) {
            var member = {};
            member.IDNumber = $("#PrincipleMember_IdNumber").val();
            $.getJSON("<%= Url.Action("MemberLookup","Member") %>", member, function(data) {
                $("#PrincipleMember_Firstname").val(data.FirstName);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

A form:

```
<fieldset class="fieldsetSection">
<legend>Principle Member</legend>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width="150px" class="editor-label"><%=Html.LabelFor(l=>l.PrincipleMember.IdNumber)%></td>
        <td class="editor-field"><%= Html.AutoCompleteTextBoxFor(i => i.PrincipleMember.IdNumber, "IdNumber", "AutoComplete")%></td>
        <td><%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(v => v.PrincipleMember.IdNumber)%></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="150px" class="editor-label"><%=Html.LabelFor(l=>l.PrincipleMember.Firstname)%></td>
        <td class="editor-field"><%=Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.PrincipleMember.Firstname)%></td>
        <td><%=Html.ValidationMessageFor(v => v.PrincipleMember.Firstname)%></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and finally a json result action:

```
public JsonResult MemberLookup(Member member)
{
    member = _memberRepository.GetMember(member.IDNumber);
    return this.Json(member);
}
```

my json result is executed perfectly and i get a result, but for some reason this section of the script is not executing: `$("#PrincipleMember_Firstname").val(data.FirstName);`

i've tried replacing it with an `alert();`, but that too is not executing.

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you check JS console for errors?

Comment: have you tryed firebug ? it tells you if there are any errors in you're js or if there are any errors when you're js get's executed . you can allso check the response you got from the ajax call .

Comment: firebug tells me: This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request. To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

Comment: argh my jsonresult should look like this: `return this.Json(m, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: Ah, there you go.. answered your question yourself :)
FireBug is a MUST in these situations :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my json result:

```
return this.Json(member, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is (assuming that your server-side method is definitely executing successfully, and returns a `200 OK` ) that your data object might not have a FirstName property.

If you use Firefox, then get FireBug, and check the value of the data object. If you're using Chrome - check the developer console (Ctrl + Shift + I)

Replace `$("#PrincipleMember_Firstname").val(data.FirstName);` with `console.log(data);` and check the javascript console (firebug's console tab, or Chrome's developer console -> console tab. You should be able to see your object, and any js errors that you might have.

If the object returns fine - try `console.log(data.FirstName);`

If the object isn't in the console - then your success method isn't executing. Maybe the server-side call isn't successful - try replace it with a `$.ajax` call, and use the error event to see what's wrong.

Also, if console.log returns undefined - your method call result probably didn't return a valid json object, though I think that'd be highly unlikely, looking at your code.